# Why does setting the prototype of an object to `Foo` not make it `instanceof Foo`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, instanceof

I am trying to use `Object.setPrototypeOf` to re-set the prototype of objects that have been converted to JSON and back into an object. However, `instanceof` doesn't seem to work the way I'd expect:

```js
class Foo {}

const obj = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, Foo);
console.log(obj instanceof Foo);
```

Why is this the case? To my knowledge `instanceof` works based on comparing the prototype of a given object to the referenced class. Is there a different way this should be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS classes are just syntactic sugar for constructor functions and prototypes. Foo is the constructor function, not the prototype...so you'd need to use `Foo.prototype` and not `Foo`:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf({ }, Foo.prototype)
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this approach for your use case due to this [warning on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf):

> Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how
>   modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow
>   operation

Instead, use `Object.create()`:

```
const obj = Object.create(Foo.prototype)
```

You can then use `Object.assign()` to copy the data (assuming that `data` is your parsed JSON data):

```
Object.assign(obj, data)
```

Alternatively, if your class has a constructor that allows you to set its initial state from an argument, you could just use `new Foo(data)`, but the above approach is more generic since it bypasses the constructor.